# No me deja limpiar un cuadro de texto largo Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text

soy nuevo por aquí, recientemente estoy viendo un curso de programación de Python, y realizando un proyecto que me propuse hacer, me encontré con un problema. Espero su ayuda.

El problema está, en que hice una función para que un botón llamado Limpiar me borre todo los campos que hay en mi ventana. LO HACE con los `Entry`, pero no me deja en el cuadro de texto largo. Pido disculpa de antemano por el desorden del código, es lo más organizado que puedo hasta el momento con el conocimiento que llevo.

Variables que uso para limpiar los campos

```
miNombre=StringVar()
miCI=StringVar()
miSexo=StringVar()
miFechaNac=StringVar()
miEdad=StringVar()
miDireccion=StringVar()
miEmail=StringVar()
miTelefono=StringVar()
```

La función

```
def limpiarCampos():

    miPaciente.set("")
    miNombre.set("")
    miCI.set("")
    miSexo.set("")
    miFechaNac.set("")
    miEdad.set("")
    miDireccion.set("")
    miEmail.set("")
    miTelefono.set("")
    textoHistorial.delete(1.0, END)
```

BOTÓN Y EL CUADRO DE TEXTO, QUE ESTÁN METIDO EN WIN, QUE ES UNA VENTANA (TOPLEVEL)

```
def NuevoPaciente():

    win=Toplevel(myFrame)
    win.title("NUEVO - DATOS DEL PACIENTE")
    win.iconbitmap("controlab.ico")
    win.resizable(0,0)
    win.geometry('580x400')
    win.focus_set()
    win.grab_set()
    LabelHistorial=Label(win, text="Historial Clínico :")
    LabelHistorial.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
    textoHistorial=Text(win, width=46, height=5)
    textoHistorial.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=3)



    # ------------SCROLL PARA LOS COMENTARIOS ----------------------

    scrollVert=Scrollbar(win, command=textoHistorial.yview)
    scrollVert.grid(row=6, column=4, sticky="nsew")

    textoHistorial.config(yscrollcommand=scrollVert.set)


  # ------------------ BOTONES DEL CREAR PACIENTES -------------------------

    botonCrear=Button(win, text="Crear")
    botonCrear.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    

    botonBorrar=Button(win, text="Borrar", command=limpiarCampos)
    botonBorrar.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    botonCancelar=Button(win, text="Cancelar")
    botonCancelar.grid(row=7, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
```

El error que me dice, es que `TextoHistorial` no está definido, pero tampoco puedo definirlo con `StringVar` porque me dice que no `delete` no funciona y se cae el programa.

Comment: OJO, el # (comentario) lo puse para que no me tirase error el programa.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta, en la misma def que están los demás?

Comment: Recuerda que python al ser lenguaje interpretado debes de crear la variable primero y después la función, es decir, tienes que crear el cuadro de texto y más abajo dejar la función

Comment: No me funciono, no se si es porque el botón está dentro de un toplevel y no en ma raíz   me dice el siguiente error:  primero me borra el cuadro de texto, y me dice _tkinter.TcIError: unknown opción "-command"

Comment: Raven,  pero la función no solo es para borrar el campo del texto, sino también el campo de los entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías realizar la siguiente modificación:

```
botonBorrar=Button(win, text="Borrar", command=lambda:limpiarCampos(textoHistorial))
```

Y luego cuando defines la función:

```
def limpiarCampos(textoHistorial):

    miPaciente.set("")
    miNombre.set("")
    miCI.set("")
    miSexo.set("")
    miFechaNac.set("")
    miEdad.set("")
    miDireccion.set("")
    miEmail.set("")
    miTelefono.set("")
    textoHistorial.delete(1.0, END)
```

Comment: Gracias, ya me funciono!!!! Ambos me ayudaron. Tenia un error también que había puesto en comando en el cuadro de texto y eso hacía que no podía ver en cuadro  cosas que pasan a los novatos jejeje, graciassss